# Can I assign "from" as variable on Python?

Tags: python

I want to do this:

```
from = 'foo'
```

But I got `Syntax Error`:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I assign variable? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: from is a reserved keyword. https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html

Comment: Did you really pick one of the few reserved keywords for your first variable assignment ever? That's really unlucky

Comment: You should be able to tell that it is reserved since most text editors will highlight keywords

Comment: For a list of reserved words, check [here](http://pentangle.net/python/handbook/node52.html) out. Those names should be avoided when naming your variables.

Answer (score 3):

No, `from` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://docs.python.org/3.0/reference/lexical_analysis.html#id8) and cannot be assigned to a different value. Any other word will work fine, for example `word = 'foo'`.

Comment: A common workaround is to append `_` to a keyword if you want to use it as a variable name: `from_ = 'foo'`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on other people's answers `from` is a keyword. It's actually a really important one to, as when you start using packages you start an import with

```
from a_package import thing
```